# What does ESRCH mean?

Tags: error-handling

Out of:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html

It's always pretty clear why an *errno code* is named a particular way except for this one.
How does **SRCH** relate to **No such process**?

Comment: Probably `grep` or `pgrep` returns it because of failure to search the process list.

Comment: My IDE, [Atom](http://atom.io), returns ESRCH when searching the package list if there is no internet connection. Purely anecdotal, and probably on purpose rather than perchance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

POSIX [`kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) documents the "search" connotation:

> [ESRCH]
>      No process or process group can be found corresponding to that specified by pid.

The [previous issue](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html) (2004) gave in the rationale more information:

> Some implementations provide semantic extensions to the kill() function when the absolute value of pid is greater than some maximum, or otherwise special, value. Negative values are a flag to kill(). Since most implementations return ***[ESRCH]*** in this case, this behavior is not included in this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, although a conforming implementation could provide such an extension.

Answer (score 6):

The string ESRCH looks cryptic, but after looking at the other errors and their strings:
(taken from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html)

- [EINVAL] The value of the sig argument is an invalid or unsupported signal number.
- [EPERM] The process does not have permission to send the signal to any receiving process.

Seems logical that E stands for error, INVAL for invalid and PERM for permission. In the same logical line, SRCH stands for search.

Error searching pid/pid group.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! I see that you've referenced the kill function and two *other* errors, but I don't yet see any supporting evidence for the Question: How does "SRCH" relate to "No such process"?

Comment: I think "search but not found", maybe?